# How onMapSharedElements works?

Tags: shared-element-transition

Using `setExitSharedElementCallback()` and `setEnterSharedElementCallback()` you are able to remap shared view elements involved in a transition.
 After overriding it just fade transition works but not `changeTransform` and `changeBounds`.
How `onMapSharedElements(names, sharedElements)` works?